# AWS SES send multiple PDF attachment Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email with multiple PDF attachments. How can I do this in AWS SES nodejs?

So far this is my code:

```
From: "test" <no-reply@email.com>\n
To: test@email.com\n
Subject: Test Subject\n
MIME-Version: 1.0\n
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n
--NextPart\n
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n\n
This is the body of the email.\n\n
--NextPart\n
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"attachment.pdf\"\n\n
BASE64 OF PDF HERE
--NextPart
```

so far the above code is working however, I want to send multiple attachments. Thank you.

Comment: Did you get some progress here? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was a mismatch on the boundaries, eg:

```
--NextPart
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n\n
This is the body of the email.\n\n

--NextPart
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"attachment.pdf\"\n\n
BASE64 OF PDF HERE

--NextPartBlaBla
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"missed-attachment.pdf\"\n\n
BASE64 OF PDF HERE
```

So, keep an eye on the boundaries.